# Are there any S3 put event limitations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I got put event (trigger) between `S3`->`Lambda function`.

I tried several files with different sizes - 1MB -> 75MB and some other small ones.

What i'm getting is that the files which are bigeer than 10MB are not rasing the event.

- Are there any limitations?
- Are they configurable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The larger files are probably being uploaded via [multipart upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html). Multipart uploads don't trigger an S3 `Put` event, they trigger a `CompleteMultipartUpload` event. You need to subscribe your Lambda function to that event type as well.

Comment: Do you know what are the limits per each event?

Comment: What type of limits are you referring to?

Comment: MB of files per each type of event

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your question. Are you asking what file size requires a multi-part upload? You can upload up to 5GB without using multipart upload but since multipart is faster and can handle errors better most S3 upload clients use multipart upload for files well under that size limit.

Comment: Let's make it simple. What is the file size limit of put event? 10MB?

Comment: I answered that question in my last comment... 5GB. Please read the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectOperations.html